Is there a way to view the manufacture date of a AMD EPYC-9754 CPU?
I bought a AMD EPYC-9754 CPU from a indiviual trader, since AMD don't sell EPYC in retail market.
I want to confirm that whether or not my CPU is a new one.
Is there a way(prefered in Linux), I can view when my CPU has been manufactured.
Thanks!

Check in /proc/cpuinfo if you have 128 cores

Won't help in this case, but for future - date code printed on top of the CPU is the official way, can take pictures of that on the chips before / as you install for later reference.

What do you mean by "new one"? Do you mean new model or new CPU chip?
AMD EPYC 9754 is part of the AMD EPYC 9004 series, and its a 4th Generation CPU. It was released in 2022.
If you want to confirm if the chip is new, then you have to physically inspect it and see the it's condition.
